# Centos use hard disks on home folder

Tags: centos

We have a centos server with around 8 hard drive (hdd) each is around 2TB, right now I only use one of the hard drives which is 2TB,now I want all the other hard drives to be used on the `/home` folder

Image explaining my server's hard disks

[image]

the red square is one of my hard drives with 3 partitions, the yellow one is my other hard disks I want the yellow hard drives to be used with the main home folder, Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. There are a number of approaches, e.g. one disk per user or partitions per user. Likely you want to use some raid setup and use a virtual disk based on the physical disks for your home.